# Increasing understanding of the formatting in Python with the format() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
hilarious = False

joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! {}"

print(joke_evaluation.format(hilarious))
```

For the following lines of Python code I'm failing to understand a key concept.

A string is assigned to the variable `joke_evaluation`and include `{}` to embed another variable within it.

The third line of code has got me stuck, we are saying print the variable `joke_evaluation` then using the `.format()` function and passing another variable to it - `hilarious` which is set as a boolean data type.

Are the `{}` effectively functioning as placeholders? How does the `.format()` function know to populate the `{}` with the variable `hilarious`?

Please explain in basic terms if possible to increase my understanding, I'm failing to understand how Python populates the curly braces `{}` as I've mentioned above.

Comment: yes, it's placeholders. and `format` is bound to `str` not to `print`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `{}` acting as placeholders, which is treated by `.format` method in special way.

> How does the .format() function know to populate the {} with the variable hilarious?

If you're providing `{}` only, it's substituted position-wise, i.e.

```
>>> 'first: {}, second: {}'.format(1, 2)
'first: 1, second: 2'
```

For more verbose or re-usable substitution you can use named arguments:

```
>>> "{actor1} tells {actor2} that he's {actor1}".format(actor1='Bob', actor2='Joel')
"Bob tells Joel that he's Bob"
```

More on awesome string formatting: [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

A bit more on formatting, when `.format` substituting placeholders with some objects, it calls [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) method on it, which

1. Accepts formatting spec — which gives you ability to control how it will be converted (for example, `'{:.2f}'.format(3.1415)`
2. Return `str`, which will actually substitute placeholders

Comment: you're forgetting that arguments are converted to `str`, which explains why booleans are printed as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of the the `format` method:

Any string with curly braces `{}` will be replaced with the variable you have provided. So, if I have a string say:

`myStr = "hello {}"`

then doing:

```
res = myStr.format("user")
print(res) #prints "hello user" without quotes.
```

Now, doing this:

```
res = myStr.format(123123)
print(res) #prints "hello 123123" without quotes.
```

As you might have guessed, the integer `123123` was implicitly converted to string before being included in the string.

Now, coming to the curly `{}` part:

1. You can have multiple curly braces and must have the same number of parameters passed to `format` method. Eg:

   `myStr = "hello {},{},{}, nice meeting you"
   res = myStr.format("abcd",123,"lol")
   print(res) #prints "hello abcd,123,lol, nice meeting you"`
2. You can even put indices in the `{}` to indicate position like `{0}` and `{1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Read Python documentation about string: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html?highlight=formatting

:) Everything you need to know. You can also change Python versions and see the behavior of formatting.

Scroll down to see examples and explanations.

Comment: Just to expand I found this useful link that explains quite well with the Returntype etc: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/

Is this kind of documentation that explains not available on the official Python docs?

Comment: @user1554264 it is! Just read the link above, it is all in there with examples and explanation.